How to globally set the CMake installation path using the project name
I frequently use CMake on Windows 10 to build C++ projects written by myself or obtained from the web. I want to override the default prefix for the install command, which is C:/Program Files/${PROJECT_NAME} for Windows. The problematic part is that I would like the new default to use the project name just like the original default, e.g. D:/ownbuilds/${PROJECT_NAME}.
I thought it was possible using the feature of CMake 3.29 by which CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX gets imported from the environment variable of the same name if it exists. But when I set the environment variable to the literal D:/ownbuilds/${PROJECT_NAME}, it does not expand to the actual project name, as verified by message( ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} ) inserted at the end of the CMakeLists file in a toy project. Also the install command behaves as if the prefix were just D:/ownbuilds without the project name.
How can I get CMake to use the project name in the overriden default installation path?
Just to clarify, the new default should affect all new projects out of the box, unless their CMakeLists specify their own installation path. Ideally it should not require me to modify the projects' original CMakeLists or use additional command line options (such as --prefix).
Generally it would be useful to know:
Can I get CMake to expand the CMake variables (the values of which may vary between projects) inside a globally set environment variable?

The sample toy/CMakeLists.txt file, as requested in the comments:
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.12...3.29 FATAL_ERROR )

project( Toy VERSION 1.0 )
add_executable( Toy main.cpp )
install( TARGETS Toy DESTINATION "bin" )

message( ">> CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}" )

Console output with the environment variable CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX equal to the literal D:/ownbuilds/${PROJECT_NAME}:
C:\Users\User\Desktop\toy\build>cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.41.34120.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.41.34120.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.41.34120/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.41.34120/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
>> CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = D:/ownbuilds/${PROJECT_NAME}
-- Configuring done (6.4s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/User/Desktop/toy/build

C:\Users\User\Desktop\toy\build>cmake --build . --config Release
MSBuild version 17.11.2+c078802d4 for .NET Framework

  1>Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/User/Desktop/toy/CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
  Toy.vcxproj -> C:\Users\User\Desktop\toy\build\Release\Toy.exe
  'pwsh.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/User/Desktop/toy/CMakeLists.txt

C:\Users\User\Desktop\toy\build>Release\Toy.exe
Hello, world!

C:\Users\User\Desktop\toy\build>cmake --install . --config Release
-- Installing: D:/ownbuilds/bin/Toy.exe

The desired behaviour is for the last line to read
-- Installing: D:/ownbuilds/Toy/bin/Toy.exe

and obviously for Toy.exe to actually get installed in the corresponding destination.

Can you add an example of a CMakeLists.txt that you use ? cmake has a few gotchas like the position of every line matters

@AhmedAEK I added a sample CMakeLists.txt file and the console output displaying the issue.

Instead of install command you should create a separate project creating proper installer / package using this projects artifacts and then install it properly.

@user7860670 What about external projects like glfw3 that also use the install command? Must I create a separate project every time I get a new source package from the web?

I think all projects use install command by default unless you manually force CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES to TRUE. For library dependencies it makes little sense. Executing an extra copy action requiring elevated privileges instead of using project content directly is just a waste of time.

Default settings of CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX are implemented in the CMake platform file Modules/CMakeGenericSystem.cmake. This file is executed in response to project() call, so the name of the project is known at this stage. You may try to write your own CMake script for set default CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, and inject this script to be executed during the project() call via CMAKE_PROJECT_TOP_LEVEL_INCLUDES variable.

@user7860670 I appreciate the willingness to help, but your instructions are unclear and unconvincing to me. If you believe it is a valid solution, please consider making it into an answer.

@Tsyvarev That's clever, but it feels quite advanced and somewhat hacky. I take it there is no standard way to achieve the result I want?

I don't know a way to define a CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX variable with the substitution of a project name. CMake evaluates dereferences (like ${VAR}) only when they are placed in CMake code. Constructions like ${VAR} specified in the command line are never evaluated by CMake.

@Tsyvarev All right, thanks for the help! I guess I will stick to -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=... (on configure) or --prefix (on install) then.
